# Почему не срабатывает margin?

Tags: css, margin

Столкнулся с проблемой отцентровки самого сайта по центру.
Смотрю разные видео - на видео всё работает, а у меня - нет.

```css
body {
  background: url(img/BG.jpg) no-repeat 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Sans-serif;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Текст не выравнивается, а всё так же ориентирован по левому верхнему краю - почему?

Может кто-то подсказать, как сразу выставлять ширину и центровку сайта по центру в `%`?

Comment: можно код на jsFidd допустим

Comment: margin отвечает за внешние отступы блока, для работы с положением текста внутри блока нужно использовать text-align

Comment: По коду CSS все правильно... Скорее всего вы не указали класс wrapper html тегу.

Comment: Поучится бесплатно можно [тут](https://www.codecademy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Добавить указатель `center`, попробуйте таким образом:

```
body{
    text-align:center;
    background: url(img/BG.jpg) no-repeat 100% center;  
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Sans-serif;  
    padding: 40px 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Блок по центру, например:

```
.wrapper{  
  width: 960px;  
  margin-left: -480px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;      
}
```

Comment: Брррррррррррр...

Answer (score 0):

Более развернутый вариант про text-align от Dmitry Kulevich

Ваш `.wrapper`, уверен на 99.9% является `div элементом`. `Div` - это блочный элемент, у блочного элемента есть свойство растягиваться на всю ширину родителя, в вашем случае, это скорее всего body, так как `html` и `body` по-умолчанию растягиваются на всю ширину экрана монитора, то и ваш wrapper тоже растянут на всю ширину. Это можно легко проверить, задайте вашему .wrapper границу `border: 1px solid #000` и вы увидите как он растянут...Идем дальше, текст в блочных элементах по-умолчанию отцентрирован слева, что вы и наблюдаете. Если вы хотите, чтобы текст был по-середине блочного элемента надо "сказать" это ему `text-align: center`

Comment: в таком случаи вы можете мне подсказать, как отцентровать сам блок по центру?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Mit9l/t129j175/3/

Comment: Вообще-то у него в приведённых стилях ширина прописана.